# Error while starting apache2 "Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log"

Tags: apache2

When I run `sudo service apache2 start` I get this error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And when I run `systemctl status apache2.service` I get this:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-15 16:20:26 -03; 7min ago
  Process: 8101 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

ene 15 16:20:26 pc systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
ene 15 16:20:26 pc apachectl[8101]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. 
ene 15 16:20:26 pc apachectl[8101]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
ene 15 16:20:26 pc apachectl[8101]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost 
ene 15 16:20:26 pc apachectl[8101]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
ene 15 16:20:26 pc apachectl[8101]: Action 'start' failed.
ene 15 16:20:26 pc apachectl[8101]: The Apache error log may have more information.
ene 15 16:20:26 pc systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
ene 15 16:20:26 pc systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ene 15 16:20:26 pc systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: The message is pretty clear: `Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/'`. Does that directory exist and is writable by the www-data user? What does `ls -ld /var/log/apache2` show?

Comment: It complains about that it can't access '/val/log/apache2` ..does it exist ?

Comment: /var/log/ is empty

Comment: That is weird because `/var/log` should contain at least a dozen or so logfiles. What Ubuntu version do you have?

Comment: Please don't ask more unrelated questions in same question. Create a new question for the second one.

Comment: I updated 18.04 to 18.10 last week, but i got the error this week

Comment: Is (or was) your `/var` on a separate filesystem?

Comment: no, but I tried to clean my system with stacer, maybe that deleted my logfiles

Comment: Yes, stacer deleted my logfiles, shoud I just create that empty directory and give it write permissions?

Comment: There is an issue on  [stacer](https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer/issues/467#issue-1051682891) related to this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Fixed**

I just created the directory and gave it write permissions:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/apache2/
sudo chmod -R 744 /var/log/apache2/
```

Comment: Is there a reason why not give it `744` permissions instead ?

Comment: I'm kind of new at this, what's the difference between 744 and 755?

Comment: [this may help you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183999/290307)