# Ubuntu 20.04 - apache does not start at boot

Tags: apache2

I got myself in a similar situation and I can't find a proper fix.

Here is my use case:

Each site I host on my laptop is configured using a file named www-example1.conf. This file's location is /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www-example1.conf

The content of this file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www-example1
        ServerAlias www.www-example1
        DocumentRoot /home/myuser/www/www-example1/public_html
        ErrorLog /home/myuser/www/www-example1/error.log
        CustomLog /home/myuser/www/www-example1/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The apache user/group is www-data. The www-example1 folder is owned by myuser:www-data. The www-example1 folder has 755 permissions. Inside this folder there are the error.log and access.log files, each with 755 permissions and owned by myuser:www-data.

**The issue is that apache fails to start on system boot.**

When I use `sudo systemctl status apache2`, the result is:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-06-18 22:58:00 EEST; 12min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 3044 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

iun 18 22:58:00 SIA-PC apachectl[3067]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/home/myuser/www/www-example1/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www-example1.conf:1
iun 18 22:58:00 SIA-PC apachectl[3067]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
iun 18 22:58:00 SIA-PC apachectl[3044]: Action 'start' failed.
iun 18 22:58:00 SIA-PC apachectl[3044]: The Apache error log may have more information.
iun 18 22:58:00 SIA-PC systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
iun 18 22:58:00 SIA-PC systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
iun 18 22:58:00 SIA-PC systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

If I start apache manually using `sudo service apache2 start`, everything works.

What can I do to make apache start at boot?

Thank you!

I already tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110046/error-while-starting-apache2-cannot-access-directory-var-log-apache2-for-ma), but to no avail. I would really like to keep my folder structure as it is.

Comment: are you sure your user is named myuser? plus could it be that you use an encrypted home folder? normally you would put your Document-root in /var/www/ have a look at this nice tutorial https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#1-overview

Comment: I use an encrypted home folder! Is there any way around this, but to move the www folder outside my home folder? apache is starting just fine if I start it manually, after boot. Maybe there could be a way to delay the auto-start of apache until after the home folder is decrypted? Just guessing... Thank you!

Comment: okay so I guess if you add `sudo service apache2 start` at the end of myusers'  `~/.profile` it  should work ?

Comment: Nope! Adding that to the ~/.profile makes the system freeze right after login.

Comment: Comment out `CustomLog` and `ErrorLog` by adding a `#` at the beginning and then try to restart apache.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem

Ubuntu 20.04 work with **libphp7.4.so** and apache2 work with **libphp7.2.so**
so to fixe it you need to change the configuration of apache2 and this is how i did it :

1- you can check this problem by testing the apache and writing : `apache2ctl configtest`

The output message :

**apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.2.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.**

2- open the file **php7.2.load** by `gedit /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.2.load`
you can see

**LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/*libphp7.2.so***

3- go to `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/` and check the version of libphp by `ls`
, it will be **libphp7.4.so**

4- back to the file and change the version :

**LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/*libphp7.4.so***

save it and restart apache2

```
systemctl start apache2.service
```

check the status :

```
systemctl status apache2.service
```

That's all :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried following the steps you provided, but it was not applicable. The apache configtest output is "Syntax OK". Also, the libraries are correctly loaded... I suspect that the issue is my encrypted home folder, as db429 suggested in a comment above.